# "Save image as.." not working in Google Chrome when using window.open() and document.write()

Tags: google-chrome, window.open, document.write, save-image

In my app I need to allow a user to right-click on an image to save the image to disk. However, I have noticed that with my particular code, Google Chrome is the only browser that doesn't allow the user to "Save image as.." unless the user first selects `Open image in new tab` and then, from there, choose to `Save image as..`.

Since all other major browsers (including Mobile Chrome) work as expected, I'm not sure if I'm not implementing my code in a standard/correct way or if the problem is with Chrome.

**Example:**

The following HTML is a stripped down version of what I am doing. It will allow you to click a button to open a new window which will contain an image.

To test/confirm the problem I described above, right-click the image and select `Save image as..` - You should notice that nothing happens. However, if you right-click the image and select `Open image in new tab`, you will be able to `Save image as..` from there.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function foo() {
            var tab = window.open();
            tab.document.write('<p>Right-click, then click "Save image as ..."</p><img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png" />');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="foo();">Open</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this a problem with Chrome or is there another way that I can use `window.open()` along with `document.write()` to get Chrome to work like other browsers (i.e. without having to, first, choose `Open image in new tab`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work. Make the tab have a location attribute. I'm not sure why this is needed, but it works for me on Chrome 48.

```
document.write('<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function foo() {
            var tab = window.open();
            tab.document.write('<p>Right-click, then click "Save image as ..."</p><img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png" />');
            tab.document.location = "#";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="foo();">Open</button>
</body>
</html>');
```

Comment: I had to set `window.location.href = "#"` then it worked for me. I'm using TypeScript.

Comment: thanks this solution works nice! about:blank url has disappeared now i see my page link with hash at the end.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! I've had the exact same problem for a couple of years and could not work out how to cure it.
I wonder why this should work? But never mind. It does! Yippee